# symfony redirect user after authentication

Tags: php, symfony

I have two bundles userBundle and xxxBundle. I want after authenticating a user in the user bundle to redirect it to the xxxBundle. But, depending on roles (ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_USER), I will redirect him to two different routes (route1, route2).

I added this controller to my userBundle

```
class SecurityController extends Controller
{
  public function loginAction()
  {
    if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
      return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('route1'));

    }
if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
      return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('route2'));

    }

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $session = $request->getSession();

    // On vérifie s'il y a des erreurs d'une précédent soumission du formulaire
    if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
      $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    } else {
      $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
      $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    }

    return $this->render('UserBundle:Security:login.html.twig', array(
      // Valeur du précédent nom d'utilisateur rentré par l'internaute
      'last_username' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
      'error'         => $error,
    ));
  }
```

But, this does not give the appropriate result: for a correct username and password, the user is redirected to the welcome symfony page.
Does anybody have an explanation for that?

I found in the symfony documentation that I can control the redirect from the login form using the hiddden field as follow:

```
{# src/Acme/SecurityBundle/Resources/views/Security/login.html.twig #}
{% if error %}
    <div>{{ error.message }}</div>
{% endif %}

<form action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />

    <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="account" />

    <input type="submit" name="login" />
</form>
```

Question : how could I parametrise the route to be responsible for user and admin.

Comment: Would it be more appropriate to use Access Control Lists (ACLs)?

Comment: Are you certain that `route1` and `route2` exist?  Symfony may be providing you with the welcome URL for routes that do not exist.  Perhaps add some debugging (var_dump/die) to see what's going on?

Comment: the routes route1 and route2 are routes of my bundle that I have defined by myself @PhillSparks

Comment: I think that the best solution is to forward from this controller in the user bundle to the controller of xxxBundle. But I don't know if this is possible. Do u have an idea about? @PhillSparks

Answer (score 3):

Use the `_target_path` input field and direct the authenticated user to a route with a controller from you. Inside the controller you check the role of the user and forward to another controller based upon that.